# Datetime changes after input to SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, node.js

In my app I'm using node `mssql` module to input datetime into a SQL Server database. The problem is that in the database `datetime` is always changed and time is one hour less then the one that I input.

```
async function insertDate(date, logIO) {
try {
    var d = new Date(date)
    var name = 'zdzmar'
    const pool = await sql.connect(config) 
    let result = await pool.request(pool)
    .input('date', TYPES.DateTime, d)
    .input('name', TYPES.VarChar, name)
    .input('logIO', TYPES.TinyInt, logIO)
    .query(`insert clock(date, name, logIO) values(@date, @name, @logIO)`)
} finally {
    sql.close();
}
}
```

Where is the problem?

Comment: Is there a timezone difference between your machines?

Comment: @Sandeep No, there is no defference

Comment: I think it's because you get UTC date using  new Date(date) in JS.

Comment: @Zet - I asked because i get same issue everyday. This is because my database server, application server and my development machine, all are at different time zone.

Comment: WHat are you passing to the function? Maybe you are passing UTC time instead of the one according to your timezone? Just compare to the values from SQL Server `SELECT GETDATE(), GETUTCDATE()`... another idea might be the daylight saving time - maybe either the App or the DB is ignoring this?

Answer (score 1):

It seems like a bug with the mssql package. I run into the same problem even when I formated the datetime into a string, the date still got converted into a different datetime, in my case 12:04pm got converted to 20:04pm, which is not directly related to timezone or UTC time.

A workaround to solve this problem is to use sql.VarChar instead of sql.DataTime.